# Not able to convert data in JSON format android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have some data which I want to convert into json object. The data I want is like

```
{"week":"Apr 22, 2019","package_id":23,"weekdata":["2019-05-07##14:00##16:45"]}
```

The weekday is of array type and others are json object type. I have done some code to convert it but I am able to convert it like

```
{"weekdata":"[\"2019-04-01##5:0##5:0\",\"2019-04-02##5:0##5:0\"]","package_id":"44","week":"Apr 01, 2019"}
```

Code for this :

Code for creating weekdata array :

```
  String firstDay = etDate1.getText().toString() + "##" + etStartTime1.getText().toString() + "##" + etEndTime1.getText().toString();
  String secondDay = etDate2.getText().toString() + "##" + etStartTime2.getText().toString() + "##" + etEndTime2.getText().toString();
 selectionItems.add(firstDay);
 selectionItems.add(secondDay);
 String[] blist = new String[selectionItems.size()];
 Log.e("tag", "array" + blist.length + selectionItems);

  for (int i = 0; i < selectionItems.size(); i++) {
        blist[i] = selectionItems.get(i);
}
 Log.e("tag", "arrayList" + blist[0]);
 weekdata = new JSONArray();


 for (int i = 0; i < blist.length; i++) {
     weekdata.put(  blist[i]  );   
 }
```

Conversion into json to send it into volley :

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

params.put("package_id", package_id);
params.put("week", weekName);
params.put("weekdata",weekdata.toString() );


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(params);
```

And I get data like :

```
{"weekdata":"[\"2019-04-01##5:0##5:0\",\"2019-04-02##5:0##5:0\"]","package_id":"44","week":"Apr 01, 2019"}
```

How can I convert it like below format:

```
 {"week":"Apr 22, 2019","package_id":23,"weekdata":["2019-05-07##14:00##16:45"]}
```

Please help.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That will not help as She defined if Map should have String, String so internally it will call the toString method().

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have defined your Map as Map and converting your list to String using toString() method. Which is generating your String with . You should define your Map as Map and don't use the toString method while putting it into the Map.

Code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put("package_id", package_id);
params.put("week", weekName);
params.put("weekdata",weekdata);


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(params);
```

One question here is why are you using Map? is there is any special reason for that?

You can create JSON directly from JSONObject.

Sample Code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("package_id", package_id);
jsonObject.put("week", weekName);
jsonObject.put("weekdata",weekdata);
```

With JSONObject you don't have to worry about generics.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question,

### How can I convert it like below format:

> {"week":"Apr 22, 2019","package_id":23,"weekdata":["2019-05-07##14:00##16:45"]}

```
String firstDay = etDate1.getText().toString() + "##" + 
etStartTime1.getText().toString() + "##" + etEndTime1.getText().toString();
String secondDay = etDate2.getText().toString() + "##" + 
etStartTime2.getText().toString() + "##" + etEndTime2.getText().toString();
selectionItems.add(firstDay);
selectionItems.add(secondDay);
String[] blist = new String[selectionItems.size()];
Log.e("tag", "array" + blist.length + selectionItems);

for (int i = 0; i < selectionItems.size(); i++) {
    blist[i] = selectionItems.get(i);
}
Log.e("tag", "arrayList" + blist[0]);
JsonArray weekdata = new JSONArray();


for (int i = 0; i < blist.length; i++) {
 weekdata.put(  blist[i]  );   
}

After this wrap this in the JsonObject



JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.put("package_id", package_id);
jsonObject.put("week", weekName); 
jsonObject.put("weekdata",weekdata);

Log.e("jsonResult",jsonObject.toString());
```

Try this and let me know @mishti.